# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Vector*'

Tags: c++, class

invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Vector*'

this is my error code:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &s1)
{
    Vector *p(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        cout<<"*****"<<endl;
        cout<<i<<endl;
        p->s[i]=s[i]+s1.s[i];
    }
    return *p;
}
```

and the class I have write:

```
class Vector
{
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in,Vector &s1);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const Vector &s1);
    private:
        int size,*s;
    public:
        Vector(int sz=0){size=sz;s=new int [size];}
        Vector operator+(const Vector &s1);
};
```

Comment: How does Vector pointer initialisation with size work exactly?

Comment: After you fix that (what is mentioned in the comment above) you need to research the rule of 3 / 5 / 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit too keen on writing the asterisk.

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &s1)
{
    Vector p(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        p.s[i]=s[i]+s1.s[i];
    }
    return p;
}
```